# Java: Gson - hashmap to JSON in custom JsonSerializer

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to create custom `JsonSerializer` for a class (and it's children).
So I'm iterating through the Fields of the class and doing stuff.
I faced with problem: If I have something like this in my class:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> nestedHashMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>() {{
    put("levelOneKey", new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
        put("levelTwoKey", 25);
    }});
}};
```

It turns into `{}`. I checked, it has elements on creation, GSON just can't handle it properly. If I'll try to use GSON without JsonSerializer, it works.
Clearly, I'm doing something wrong. I don't have much experience with Java Reflection.

Part of my code:

```
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(JsonConfig src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonObject o = new JsonObject();
    //...
    Field[] fields = src.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        Object fieldValue = null;
        try {
            fieldValue = field.get(src);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.print("IllegalAccessException for field " + field.getName() + ": " + e.toString());
            continue;
        }
        o.add(field.getName(), context.serialize(fieldValue, field.getType()));
    }
    //...
}
```

I tried to create another instance of Gson and replace `o.add` with:

```
o.add(field.getName(), gson.toJson(fieldValue, field.getType()));
```

I checked, `fieldValue` has elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `field.getType()`, you should change it to `field.getGenericType()`.

```
o.add(field.getName(), context.serialize(fieldValue, field.getGenericType()));
```

If you print both values to the console, the `.getType()` returns just a `java.util.Map`, but the `.getGenericType()` returns the actual type of your map `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`